# java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Estoy tratando de guardar como una imagen, lo que contiene un LinearLayout (incluyendo su fondo) y los editText dentro del LinearLayout. Lo tengo implementado de la siguiente manera en Lenguaje Java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout backgroundLayout;
    private EditText editText1;
    private EditText editText2;
    private Button saveButton;
    private int imageCounter = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        backgroundLayout = findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
        editText1 = findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        editText2 = findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        saveButton = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Combina el fondo y el texto en un solo Bitmap
                Bitmap combinedBitmap = createCombinedBitmap();

                // Guarda la imagen con un nombre único
                saveImageToFile(combinedBitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    private Bitmap createCombinedBitmap() {
        Bitmap backgroundBitmap = loadBackgroundBitmap();
        String text1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        String text2 = editText2.getText().toString();

        // Combina el fondo y el texto en un solo Bitmap
        Bitmap combinedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                backgroundBitmap.getWidth(),
                backgroundBitmap.getHeight(),
                backgroundBitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(combinedBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(backgroundBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        // Agrega el texto a la imagen
        return combinedBitmap;
    }

    private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap() {
        Bitmap backgroundBitmap = loadBackgroundBitmap();
        if (backgroundBitmap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "This Background Bitmap is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return null;
        }
        return backgroundBitmap;
    }
    private void saveImageToFile(Bitmap imageBitmap) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);

        // Crea un nombre de archivo único basado en el contador
        String fileName = "imagen_" + imageCounter + ".png";
        File file = new File(directory, fileName);

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            // Notifica al usuario que la imagen se ha guardado con éxito
            Toast.makeText(this, "Imagen guardada en " + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Incrementa el contador
            imageCounter++;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error al guardar la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // Maneja cualquier error que pueda ocurrir al guardar la imagen
        }
    }
}
```

Pero al ejecutar la aplicación y oprimir el botón guardar me sale el siguiente error:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB en el loadBackgroundBitmap(`private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap`)

Comment: `Bitmap backgroundBitmap = loadBackgroundBitmap();` ahí estás haciendo recursión infinita

Comment: Juan: tanto Lobos como Mateo te han dicho específicamente cuál es el problema. Pensalo: si una función se está llamando a sí misma infinitamente, ¿cuál es entonces la solución? Razonalo.

Answer (score 2):

`StackOverflow` sucede cuando la pila de llamadas se llena, es más frecuente en código recursivo.

Si prestas atención, la función `loadBackgroundBitmap` es recursiva e infinita. Nada más entrar a la función ya está llamándose de nuevo a sí misma.

Tal vez hayas querido llamar a otra función.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, la verdad soy nuevo en esto, voy a actualizar el codigo en la pregunta, porfa si me puedes ayudar a solucionar este error.

Comment: En realidad es una respuesta. Ya te dije donde está el problema pero no puedo ayudarte sin tener ningún indicio de qué otra función podrías haber querido llamar.

Comment: Ya actualice la pregunta junto con el codigo, si le puedes echar un vistazo

Answer (score 1):

El problema se indica en el mensaje:

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB en el
> loadBackgroundBitmap(private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap)

se debe a que al llamar al método loadBackgroundBitmap() realiza una llamada recursiva del mismo método infinitamente. Si revisas el método, este se esta llamando a si mismo pero

```
private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap() {
    Bitmap backgroundBitmap = loadBackgroundBitmap();
    if (backgroundBitmap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "This Background Bitmap is null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
    }
    return backgroundBitmap;
}
```

**Solución:**

En realidad tu método debería obtener un Bitmap a partir de la imagen que salvaste previamente.

```
private Bitmap loadBackgroundBitmap() {

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    File directory = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);     
    String fileName = "imagen_" + imageCounter + ".png";
    File file = new File(directory, fileName);

    String filePath = file.getPath();  
    backgroundBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
    return backgroundBitmap;
}
```